# Error while Imports .less file in main.less

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am importing `.less` files in my /client/main.less file. If I add more than one import, I am getting error. If I add only one line, no issues. Please help.

```
// Global namespace

@import "/imports/ui/stylesheets/panel.less";

@import "/imports/ui/stylesheets/menubar.less";
```

getting below error,

```
=> Modified -- restarting.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While minifying app stylesheet:

   C:\Users\lawren\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\juliancwirko_postcss\1.1.1\plugin.minifier-postcss.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\minifier-postcss\node_mo
dules\source-map\lib\array-set.js:80:9:
   "client/main.less" is not in the set.
   at ArraySet_indexOf
   (C:\Users\lawren\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\juliancwirko_postcss\1.1.1\plugin.minifier-postcss.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\minifier-postcss\node_m
odules\source-map\lib\array-set.js:80:9)
   at SourceMapGenerator_serializeMappings
   (C:\Users\lawren\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\juliancwirko_postcss\1.1.1\plugin.minifier-postcss.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\minifier-postcss\node_m
odules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:330:35)
   at SourceMapGenerator_toJSON
   (C:\Users\lawren\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\juliancwirko_postcss\1.1.1\plugin.minifier-postcss.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\minifier-postcss\node_m
odules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:381:22)
   at SourceMapGenerator_toString
   (C:\Users\lawren\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\juliancwirko_postcss\1.1.1\plugin.minifier-postcss.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\minifier-postcss\node_m
odules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:401:32)
   at mergeCss (<runJavaScript-45>:295:27)
   at CssToolsMinifier.processFilesForBundle (<runJavaScript-45>:136:18)


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: have you tried removing the '/' at the beginning of the path ?

Comment: yes i tried. Still getting the same error. FYI, my Meteor version is 1.4.1.1

Comment: never used meteor but it seems you need to use a .import.less extension to import less files  (wouldn't explain why it works with one file but not two though)  https://docs.meteor.com/packages/less.html

Comment: Since i am new to meteor i was exploring different packages and one of the package gave this issue. I have removed everything and tried again. Its working now. Thanks for your help.